# Django/Parler: unable to access the translated fields of a model in the update_or_create function

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-parler

I have a model such as below:

```
class MyModel(TranslatableModel):
    date_created = models.DateField(
        verbose_name=_('Date Created'), default=timezone.now)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=('Type'))
    translations = TranslatedFields(
        name=models.CharField(verbose_name=_('Name'), max_length=200)
    )
```

I want to use update_or_create function on this model; I want to fetch a record which has the given id and source; If it exists I want to update its name in 3 different languages. Otherwise I want to create a new record.
I used the following code. I tried name_en, name__en, translations__name_en; None of them worked. I also tried get_or_create function, None of them worked with that as well.

```
obj, created = MyModel.objects.update_or_create(
                                            id= id,
                                            source = 'tmp',
                                            defaults={
                                                    'name_en': en_name,
                                                    'name_fi': fi_name,
                                                    'name_sv': sv_name,
                                             })
```

I don't want to use get function and create function separately. I would like to know how to access the django translated fields via update_or_create function or get_or_create function.
Can some one help me with this please?

My Django version:
Django==1.11.17

Comment: What package do TranslateFields come from

Comment: @iklinac : from parler.models import TranslatableModel, TranslatedFields

Answer (score 1):

[update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) creates object/updates object fields and it is not built to create related models/update fields on related model

> This is meant as a shortcut to boilerplatish code. For example:
>
> ```
> defaults = {'first_name': 'Bob'}
> try:
>     obj = Person.objects.get(first_name='John', last_name='Lennon')
>     for key, value in defaults.items():
>         setattr(obj, key, value)
>     obj.save()
> except Person.DoesNotExist:
>     new_values = {'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Lennon'}
>     new_values.update(defaults)
>     obj = Person(**new_values)
>     obj.save()
> ```

And as [documented](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler#accessing-fields)

> Internally, django-parler stores the translated fields in a separate
> model, with one row per language.

Also same is visible from [source](https://github.com/django-parler/django-parler/blob/master/parler/models.py#L108)

Comment: This solution doesn't solve my problem. I want to update the name of the object in 3 different languages. So I need to somehow access to the translations field. Your solution is for updating the fiels of one simple model which doesn't contain any translation field!

Comment: This is a sample for accessing a translation field based on ONE language: obj, created = MyModel.objects.language('de').get_or_create(id = 'sample', translations__name = 'sample_name') . But I want to do this for MULTIPLE languages at once.

Comment: This is simply answer to your question, which was if you can use update_or_create and answer to that is : no you can not for this particular reason.